# One ActionListener for many JButtons

Tags: java, swing, jbutton, actionlistener

I would like to add an `ActionListener` to a group of buttons.
Is there any class that wrap the buttons?  Something like `GroupJButtons` or something more generally group of objects? so I can set an `ActionListener` to all of them.
After all I don't really care which buttons is pressed I just want to change his text so all I need to do is casting it to a `JButton` and changing the text.

The whole process would reduce the code lines in 1 or 2 (in case you use a loop) but I want to do that since it sounds logically better.

Comment: It is a very unusual GUI that has many buttons do *exactly* the same thing.  What is the use-case?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In this case you can extend the AbstractAction class and simply apply the same action to many buttons.

```
  class MyAction extends AbstractAction {
       public MyAction(String text, ImageIcon icon,
                  String desc, Integer mnemonic) {
       super(text, icon);
       putValue(SHORT_DESCRIPTION, desc);
        putValue(MNEMONIC_KEY, mnemonic);
   }
   public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        //do the action of the button here
    }
  }
```

Then for each button that you want the same thing to happen you can:

```
 Action myAction = new MyAction("button Text", anImage, "Tooltip Text", KeyEvent.VK_A);
 button = new JButton(myAction);
```

Comment: Very nice solution! But doesn't it seem a bit overkill? just for a group of buttons?

Comment: @Arno: it doesn't seem over-kill to me. 1+ for the good answer. You could create one MyAction object and use it to create many buttons, if all buttons will have the same text and action. Now if the buttons will have different titles, then you may need to instead create one ActionListener that is then added to several buttons.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels, yes my solution demonstrates approach for buttons with different titles

Comment: In the above example if you want different text and images per button then you create different instances of MyAction with different parameters. You can modify the constructor to suit yourself.

Answer (score 4):

You can use this to create each button

```
private JButton createButton(String title, ActionListener al) {
    JButton button = new JButton(title);
    button.addActionListener(al);
    return button;
}
```

And this to process the action

```
public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent ae) {
    JButton button = (JButton)ae.getSource();
    button.setText("Wherever you want");
}
```